# How can I avoid to generate new session using Keycloak Spring Boot rest template?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, resttemplate, keycloak

I'm developing 2 web-apps using Spring Boot, and I'm also using Keycloak to manage authentication and authorization..

Then I exposed some `apis` from the app1. These apis are called from app2 using a KeycloakRestTemplate.

Here an example:

```
@Autowired
private KeycloakRestTemplate restTemplate;

......

JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(restTemplate.getForEntity(URI.create(API_URL, String.class).getBody());
```

and I configured the rest template in this way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {  


    @Autowired
    public KeycloakClientRequestFactory keycloakClientRequestFactory;

...

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public KeycloakRestTemplate keycloakRestTemplate() {
        return new KeycloakRestTemplate(keycloakClientRequestFactory);
    }
...

}
```

Until here it works perfectly, but I discover that when I use this rest template, it generate a new session for each call.
How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're using it. You're declaring your `RestTemplate` with the PROTOTYPE scope, so you've got one bean created each time you request it. That's what the PROTOTYPE scope [is all about](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html). Also if you inject it only once but you're testing it in a sample program that you launch once and again, you'll have many bean creations. Usually, I inject the `RestTemplate` in a service:

```
@Service
public class RemoteAccessService{

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public RemoteAccessService(RestTemplate restTemplate){
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        //Use restTemplate here
    }

}
```

The Spring `Service` is created as a SINGLETON, so the `RestTemplate` is requested only once.

Comment: So, instead of PROTOTYPE which scope should I use? I tried to use SINGLETONE and I also moved the RestTemplate inside a service, but I have a new session every time I use it

Comment: and please, not that I'm using KeycloakRestTemplate and inside the cnfigurtion the bean is created with keycloakClientRequestFactory, which ha scope PROTOTYPE

Comment: `KeycloakClientRequestFactory` has a PROTOTYPE scope, that means the bean is created once each time you request it. However, if you request it only once, it shouldn't be created more than one time. You can still check it with a breakpoint in `KeycloakClientRequestFactory`'s constructor.

Comment: Ok, but if I have a list and for each element I have to call a rest request, I have registered on tomcat 30 session for example.. I don't know, but it seems to me, not the best soltuion.. or not?

Comment: It shouldn't create a new session.

Comment: So, what do you think I'm doing wrong? How can I figure out the reason?

Comment: I would put a breakpoint in `KeycloakClientRequestFactory`'s constructor, to see if it's being recreated more than once, as I stated couple of comments above. If it is, then it might be your configuration problem, if not, then it's the adapter handling the flux incorrectly.